# Cannot get request_ids from notification in Facebook iOS App

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-requests

I have a iOS app to send the apprequest by facebook ios sdk. I also set the Canvas URL and the Native iOS App in the developers.facebook.com.

When send a apprequest, a notification show in notifacation list of facebook iOS app, tap the notification, my iOS app has been launch and the openURL method has been invoke, but the URL doesn't contain the request_ids.

The URL like this:

fb[myappid]://authorize#expires_in=3600&access_token=xxx&target_url=http://apps.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=[myappid]

Am I doing something wrong?

PS. the canvas URL is work fine, when click the notification on facebook website, request_ids  be passed to canvas URL as expected.

Comment: It works when I re-install the facebook ios app. So, I think it's a bug of facebook ios app.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me with my Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you not only set a canvas URL for an "App on Facebook", but also as **"Mobile Web"** and insert a "Mobile Site URL".

Here the screenshot from the [Facebook iOS SDK HowTo: Send Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/)

[image: Mobile Web]